# Multi-site error wordpress after migration

Tags: plugins, customization, migration

I am trying to migrate a WordPress multi-site to a sub domain. I am using wordPress version is 3.1 and PHP version in 5.4.

I am getting this warning: "Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /**/**/public_html/wp-includes/ms-load.php on line 139"

I have migrated everything, but I don't know how to fix this issue.

Anybody please help me?

Comment: there is zero point in asking a question about a prehistoric wordpress version.

Comment: I am using that version so i asked question. whats is the problem here. if you can help me out then please